# How to sort date: YYYY.MM.DD. HH:MM?

Tags: sort

INPUT:

```
b|2013.06.03. 18:47|
a|2013.06.03. 13:15|
c|2013.06.03. 13:53|
```

needed OUTPUT:

```
a|2013.06.03. 13:15|
c|2013.06.03. 13:53|
b|2013.06.03. 18:47|
```

How can I sort the dates correctly in ascendant order? The delimiter is the `|`.

P.S.

```
sort -t "|" -n -k 2
```

is not enough, because it doesn't put the HH:MM in good order, only the YYYY.MM.DD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
sort -t "|"  -k 2
```

By leaving out the -n, you sort on the whole string between '|' characters not just the first number that can be made out of that string (`2013`).